# Some Ajax requests failing in ezproxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, proxy

Im Having some issues with EZproxy. I have some javascript that is firing multiple Ajax requests. The Ajax requests check to see if there is a custom comment associated with a procedure. If there is then load the comment otherwise insert an add comment button. When accessing the site directly there are no issues and all the custom comments/add comment are being rendered correctly with no errors in my console. However, when accessing the site via EZproxy only some of the comments/buttons are being added and i am getting 401 unauthorised errors every time a comment/button fails to be loaded. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how i can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EzProxy is based on a "whitelist" config file containing the domain names to which it can access.

If it is not done yet, I would advise you to ask to the EZproxy administrator to add to the config file, if your domain is located at example.com :

```
HJ example.com
DJ example.com
```

That should limit the number of issues with Javascript going through EZproxy. Otherwise, try to have a look at [all the config options of EZproxy](https://www.oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/documentation/cfg/config-txt-intro.en.html).